# Retrieving and rendering data fed via Django forms API

Tags: django, forms

I have prepared a basic contact form in Django. The data gets saved successfully. But I want to retrieve the saved data (all db columns) as a html table and display it on my site (not in the admin interface).

Here is the model:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Your name')
    place = forms.CharField(max_length=100,label='Your place')
    message = forms.CharField(label='Your message')
    url = forms.URLField(label='Your Web site', required=False)
    options = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    day = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)
```

The view only accepts the post data and redirects to a "thanks" page.

I tried doing `ContactForm.objects.all()` but the error I got was: `Objects attribute does not exist for ContactForm`.

Comment: You can call objects.all() on model, not on form. Could you add model code to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to create a [model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/). A django model describes a database table and creates the functionality to handle that table with python. If you want to save your data then you're going to want it saved in the database, and you're going to want a model for that.

Try something like -

```
from django.db import models

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=128)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=100,label='Your place')
    message = models.CharField(label='Your message', max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField(label='Your Web site', required=False)
    options = models.BooleanField(required=False)
    day = models.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)
```

Then instead of creating a form that inherits from `Form` you want to inherit from `ModelForm` (see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/) for more info on Model Forms). It should be pretty simple because all you're fields are already described on the model -

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
```

You'll need a view that will handle saving the form ([here's an example from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-model-formset-in-a-view)). Then you'll be able to do `Contact.objects.all()` and follow the example from Cathy's answer to display it. Alternatively, check out [Django-Tables2](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) - a useful plugin for displaying tables.

Answer (score 0):

**views.py**

```
def view_name (request):
    contacts = Contact.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'page.html', {
        'contacts': contacts
    })
```

**html**

```
<html>
    ....

    <body>
        <table>
        {% for contact in contacts %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.place}}</td>
                <td>....</td>
                <td>....</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```